# jQuery.load() wrapper to manage multiple requests and ".loading" CSS class

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I am using `.load()` extensively for AJAX content. It's great but I would like it if it did a little more:

1. If, in response to user actions, I make multiple calls to `.load()` on the same div, I can end up with the wrong data in the div.  This happens when an earlier request is slower to callback than a later one. I need something to reject out-of-date callbacks
2. It would be nice if `.load()` added a CSS class to the target... and removed that class after callback completed.

Is there a library or plugin for jQuery that offers such functionality? Or can it be done in so few lines that it's not worth a plugin?

Comment: As far as your second requirement is concerned, just add the class at the beginning of the load handler and remove it at the end using `addClass`, `removeClass`.

Comment: Or centralize the add/remove class logic inside [`$.ajaxStart`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and `$.ajaxComplete`, referencing the element with `this` from within the handler. It's trivial.

Comment: IF you make multiple request it will be better to use the .get() method or an equivalent in order to avoid "old requested content" being added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's super easy to create your own plugin that prevents multiple concurrent requests. Here's a simple plugin that intercepts AJAX calls, keeps a list of outstanding requests and aborts them when a new one comes in:

```
$.fn.preventConcurrentAjax = function() {
    return this.ajaxSend(function(e, jqXHR, settings) {
        $.each($(this).data("pca-pending") || [], function() { this.abort(); });
        $(this).data("pca-pending", [jqXHR]);
    });
};
```

You can easily extend this so that it cancels earlier requests that are still outstanding when a request *completes* instead of when one is queued; to do this you will also need to store a timestamp with each request.

You can also use jQuery's [`.ajaxStart()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [`.ajaxStop()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) to trivially automate toggling a "loading" class, for example:

```
$.fn.loadingOnAjax = function() {
    var $self = $(this);
    return this.ajaxStart(function() { $self.addClass("loading"); })
               .ajaxStop(function() { $self.removeClass("loading"); });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

That is easily done without plugin:

```
function ajaxLoad() {
    $('#result')
        .addClass('isLoading')
        .load('ajax/test.html', function() {
            $('#result').removeClass('isLoading');
        });
}
```

And to stop multiple ajax calls, check:

```
if( ! $('#result').hasClass('isLoading') ) {
    ajaxLoad();
}
```

Comment: I want to allow multiple ajax calls with only the most recent ajax call being processed further.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the xhr object to cancel previous requests.

```
( function load( ) {
    var xhr;

    return function( url ) {

        // abort previous request
        if( xhr && xhr.readystate != 4 ) { xhr.abort(); }

        xhr = $.get(url, function (data) {
            $('#id').html(data);
        });
    };
}());

load( url );
```